# Spinner while data from API is pulled (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, html

I have an html document which is gathering data from an api.  As the data is being retrieved, there is a loadtime, usually 1-3 seconds.  I want to incorporate a spinner or some sort, whether spin.js or a gif, while the data is loading, so the user knows data is being retrieved.  How do I go about adding a spinner while the data is being loaded, to the function loaddata()?

Here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://api.eventful.com/js/api"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    //Function which loads data from API.
    function loaddata() {
        //get vars 
        var oArgs = {
            app_key: "(HIDDEN FOR SECURITY PURPOSES)",
            q: "music",
            where: "San Diego", 
            "date": "2013061000-2015062000",
            page_size: 5,
            sort_order: "popularity",
        };

        var content = '';

        //API CALL
        EVDB.API.call("/events/search", oArgs, function(oData) {
            console.log(oData)
            //Get the title for each item
            for (var i = 0;i < oData.events.event.length;i++) {
                content += oData.events.event[i].title + '<br><br>';
            }

            // Show Data on page
            $("#ListItems").html(content);
        });
    }
</script>
<body>
    <input type = "button" id="target" value="search" onclick="loaddata();"/>
    <br><br>

    //Where Data is presented.
    <span id = "ListItems"></span>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: show spinner at the beginning of `loaddata`, hide spinner in the callback function of `EVDB.API.call`

Comment: Thank you Brian!  Can you give an example in code please so I can mark your answer as correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The typical way to achieve this is to show the spinner / loading graphic when the remote data is requested, and to hide the spinner when the request completes. In your case you could do something like the following:

```
$spinner = $('#loadingSpinner'); //element that contains spinner

//API CALL
$spinner.show();

EVDB.API.call("/events/search", oArgs, function(oData) {
    console.log(oData)
  // Hide spinner
  $spinner.hide();
  //Get the title for each item
  for (var i = 0;i < oData.events.event.length;i++){
    content += oData.events.event[i].title + '<br><br>';
  }
      // Show Data on page
      $("#ListItems").html(content);
    });
}
```

Comment: You also probably want to hide the spinner when the request fails as well, if your API lets you provide an error callback function.